# Get Date with Day of Week, Week Number, Month and Year

Tags: mysql, sql, date

There some kind to get the Date if you have only the Day of Week, Week number, Month and Year with MySQL?

Example:

I Want to know which day is with this parameters:

- Year : 2014
- Month : Setember (09)
- Week number of Year : 37 OR Week number in Setember : 3
- Day of Week: Thursday

The Answer is '2014-09-18'

Comment: How are they stored in you MySQL database?

Comment: All the date functions are here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html There's no built-in function that does this, but you could probably calculate it by starting with `date_add(<year>-01-01, INTERVAL <week#> WEEKS)`

Comment: Actually i made a query grouping by week number, and separated by columns with the week days, but now I need to show something like a calendar in Mysql, showing the days itself.

Comment: @brunodotcom post the result of your query cause i need to see how you data are represented

Comment: @AndreDuarte sorry for delay, i made a sqlfiddle to show how is my query .http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e1f5/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in portuguese Stake Overflow, and they found a simple solution.

Using str_to_date, year, week number and day of week.

```
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
%U  Week (00..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week
%W  Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)

SELECT  str_to_date('201437 Thursday', '%Y%U %W');
```

Result:

```
2014-09-18 00:00:00
```

Portuguese Stack Overflow Answer Link : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33046/obter-data-com-dia-da-semana-n%C3%BAmero-da-semana-m%C3%AAs-e-ano/33063#33063

Thanks to everyone who helped me

Answer (score 0):

Using Barmars suggestion you can build a calendar of the year on the fly and check it against your constraints about that:

```
SET @year := 2014;      -- set the year of the constraints
SET @week := 37;        --     the week
SET @day_of_week := 5;  --     the day of the week (numerical)

-- build the first of the wanted year as supposed by Barmar 
SET @first_of_year = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@year, '-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'); 

SELECT
    @first_of_year + INTERVAL t.n DAY the_date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 AS n
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
       ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) c
    ORDER BY n
) t   
WHERE
    t.n < TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, @first_of_year, @first_of_year + INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND
    WEEK(@first_of_year + INTERVAL t.n DAY) = @week
AND
    DAYOFWEEK(@first_of_year + INTERVAL t.n DAY) = @day_of_week
;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b5cb/2)

**Note**
The UNION generates the numbers from 0 to 399, so we can generate a calendar of the year. Now we can apply your other constraints like week in year and day of week.

Comment: I tested here and works fine, but I found other way. Thank you very much!